# Appium WebdriverIO Browser Stack cannot read spec file

Tags: automated-tests, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android, browserstack

Please view the following video [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xhper25zelhwlnz/Setting%20up%20browser%20Stack%20in%20WebdriverIO.mov?dl=0)

I have used browser stack a number of times past but I've never set it up from scratch before.

Here are the details from the browserstack wdio file:

the section with the Error

[image]

If try to run the test using the command `npx wido android.bs.js` I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue.

first I have make some modifications to login details to the wido config file

```
user: XXX
password: XXX
```

Then the next thing that I had to modify my capabilities my widio file (in this case for android) to meet BS standards (the ones I was told to use were incorrect)

```
project: "Blah blah blah project title",
    build: 'Webdriverio Android',
    name: 'first_test',
    device: 'Google Pixel 3',
    os_version: "9.0",
    app: "bs://add-your-browserstack-app-no-here"
```

then I had to make a change to `package.json scripts` to `"wdio_android_bs":"wdio run ./wdio_android_bs.conf.js"`

Ran file with : `npm run wdio_android_bs`

I was able to run the file successfully in browser stack.